# remove the html tags from drupal tokens

Tags: php, drupal

In an email confirmatory message , I am using drupal tokens to generate values dynamically. However, the html tags are also getting passed. How do i remove the html tags from the drupal tokens.

`//Email confirmatory message.`

Group: [message:group-name]

Author: [message_author:user]

Message: [message:message-body]  //html tags are sent in the message body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the heredocs syntax: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

I got the idea to do so from here: http://drupal.org/node/252881

It works for me. Hope that it does for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Drupal sanitization functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/group/sanitization/7).

Comment: I could've used strip_tags easily, but the text is inside the token [message:message-body] and not inside a php variable $message. How can i use these functions on this token?